# Are unbound variables allowed in Lambda Calculus?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

Hello i am trying to understand lambda calculus, unfortunately i am confused on the topic of unbound variables. 
Here is a list i got from my professor about valid lambda expressions (No idea why he doesn't use dots like i see everywhere else on the internet btw)

[image: lambda expressions]

Now i am confused about a couple of them. Say the fifth one: Lambda x.(xy)
Why is this a valid expression? I don't think i can use this expression like this for example, because y is unbound : (Lambda x.(xy)) 5

Here are some exercises i tried:

[image: ex]

Are these answers correct?

a)Yes

b)Yes

c)Yes

d)No

e)Yes

f)Yes

g)Yes

It all doesn't feel right, it would all be more logical if unbound variables would not be allowed. Then the answers would look something like this:

a)Yes

b)No

c)Yes

d)No

e)Yes

f)No

g)No

I think I am close to understanding this but i need a last push in the back to get it fully. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having unbound (free) variables in your expression. They are typically just considered to be in global scope.

It is very similar to stating:

```
f(x) = x^y
```

where clearly x is a bound local variable, and y is a free global. We don't have enough information presented to solve f(x) for a given value of x numerically, but algebraically, `f(5) = 5^y`.

By the same logic it is valid to say `(λx.y)(...) = y`. We don't have a value for that y, but we don't need to.

What do you call a lambda without free variables? A **combinator**. It's funny because it's true.